# DjangoCMS products and catalog

Tags: python, django, django-cms

I want to create DjangoCMS website which shows only a product list and has a filter function. Is there such plugin? Can you suggest me?

Answer (score 0):

Django will require technical skills to implement a particular package in any case. You can take a look at [django-shop](https://github.com/awesto/django-shop).

Otherwise consider website builders, such as [Wix](https://wix.com) or [Shopify](https://shopify.com).